# How to extract global variables values at the end of each experiment in Netlogo Behaviour Space

Tags: netlogo

I am running Netlogo program to simulate if a drunk person manages to cross to another side of the pier safely. I then stored this result in a global variable.

Now I would like to run a repetition of this simulation 100x through BehaviorSpace to find out the percentages of different outcomes.

However, I am unable to extract the value of that variable at the end of each repetition.

I would like to ask if there are any ways I can extract the value of a global variable at the end of each repetition in BehaviorSpace.

Thank you.

Comment: it depends on how you're using the global, but most likely you'll want to throw it in to the behavior space settings as per the first answer. what is the global (string, number, etc.) and how are you querying it in behavior space that's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just at the global to `Measure runs using these reporters`.

If you only want the last result, uncheck `Measure runs at every step`.

If you have other things you want to report every step and you insist on not recording the global at every step, you can add to `Final commands` to write the value to a separate file.

Comment: I wrote a reporter to report the value then uncheck 'Measure runs at every step' and I got what I wanted. Thanks!